# Rename Column Name in Athena AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, hive, amazon-athena

I have tried several ways to rename some column name in athena table.

after reading the following article

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/alter-table-replace-columns.html

But I have get a no luck on it.

I tried

```
ALTER TABLE "users_data"."values_portions" REPLACE COLUMNS ('username/teradata' 'String', 'username_teradata' 'String')
```

Got error

```
no viable alternative at input 'alter table "users_data"."values_portions" replace' (service: amazonathena; status code: 400; error code: invalidrequestexception; request id: 23232ssdds.....; proxy: null)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/types-of-updates.html#updates-renaming-columns) document which talks about renaming columns. The query that you are trying to run will replace all the columns in the existing table with provided column list.

One strategy for renaming columns is to create a new table based on the same underlying data, but using new column names. The example mentioned in the [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/types-of-updates.html#updates-renaming-columns) creates a new orders_parquet table called orders_parquet_column_renamed. The example changes the column `o_totalprice` name to `o_total_price` and then runs a query in Athena.

Another way of changing the column name is by simply going to `AWS Glue -> Select database -> select table -> edit schema -> double click on column name -> type in new name -> save`.

Comment: there are almost 500 columns its a headache to do this

Comment: then you can try something like this 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/59202845/4326922